# Supervisor can't find Run command of Vapor App

Tags: swift, ubuntu, supervisord, vapor

I am attempting to set up Supervisor to run a sample Vapor app written in Swift 5.8 on an Ubuntu 22.04 server (I have also tried on 20.4 with the same result). The app was created with `vapor new hello -n` and runs fine with `swift run App serve --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 8080`.

I have copied the .conf file for Supervisor from the Vapor documentation and placed it at /etc/supervisor/conf.d/hello.conf. My username is also "vapor". The contents of the file are as follows:

```
[program:hello]
command=/home/vapor/hello/.build/release/Run serve --env production
directory=/home/vapor/hello/
user=vapor
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)-stderr.log
```

I have verified that the path /home/vapor/hello/.build/release/ exists after running
`swift build -c release --disable-sandbox --enable-test-discovery`. But there is no Run file.

Upon running:

```
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl add hello
supervisorctl start hello
```

I receive the error message: `hello: ERROR (no such file)`.

Running `sudo supervisorctl status` provides the more detailed message:
`FATAL can't find command '/home/vapor/hello/release/.build/Run'`.

Restarting Supervisor did not help. Does somebody knows what I am missing?

Comment: Why are you trying to set up supervisor in Cloud Run? That is completely unnecessary and wastes both the memory and CPU resources that you pay for with zero benefits.

Comment: Is the Ubuntu in question provided by (or running on) any particular hosting service?

Comment: yes it is running on hostinger.de

Comment: @JohnHanley Vapor recommends supervisor to autostart and auto restart the program when running on a server. Do you have a better solution I should try instead?

Comment: Vapor might recommend supervisor when running under an operating system, but Cloud Run is different. Cloud Run receives a request for your app, and starts a container if necessary. Your app starts with the container. When your app returns the response, your app is finished. This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/lifecycle-container-cloud-run) explains the lifecycle of a Cloud Run app.

Comment: One of the goals of supervisor is to restart failed apps. In Cloud Run that will not happen. If your app fails, Cloud Run will destroy the container and start a new container. Cloud Run is your `supervisor`.

Comment: Thank you for the tipp! I will definitely check out Cloud Run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vapor app is using a new executable target, called `App`. However supervisor is referring to a binary called `Run` which doesn't exist, hence the error.

Change your supervisor config to

```
[program:hello]
command=/home/vapor/hello/.build/release/App serve --env production
directory=/home/vapor/hello/
user=vapor
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)-stderr.log
```

Comment: vapor/docs issue reported [Supervisor: release/Run -> release/App #837](https://github.com/vapor/docs/issues/837)

Comment: I got "2023-11-02T07:19:01+0000 warning codes.vapor.application : [Vapor] ConsoleKit.ConsoleError(identifier: "unknownInput", reason: "Input not recognized: --env production")". Do you guys get this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you adding `serve`?

Comment: Sure. It is .build/release/App serve --env production